# Пропала русская раскладка в симуляторе iOS 8

Tags: xcode, ios

После установки xcode 6.1 не могу сменить клавиатуру в симуляторе на русскую, хотя в настройках она присутствует. Скриншоты: 
[1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/93c7jo6z7f1vn2s/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2021%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82.%202014%20%D0%B3.%2C%2013.43.37.png?dl=0), [2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8psevxze4h8w8a/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2021%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82.%202014%20%D0%B3.%2C%2013.44.04.png?dl=0), [3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhd35bqgyoqjysd/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2021%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82.%202014%20%D0%B3.%2C%2013.44.07.png?dl=0).

Пробовал сбрасывать настройки симулятора и переустанавливать xcode - без результатов. Кто-нибудь знает, как это вылечить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаю, как решить данную проблему.

Если прочесть Xcode Release Notes, то там написано:

> Localization and Keyboard settings
> (including 3rd party keyboards) are
> not correctly honored by Safari, Maps,
> and developer apps in the iOS 8.1
> Simulator. [NSLocale currentLocale]
> returns en_US and only the English and
> Emoji keyboards are available.
> (18418630, 18512161)

То есть в симуляторе по умолчанию только клавиатура en_US. Проблема решается следующим образом:

1. В Xcode выбрать active scheme.
2. Далее Edit Scheme.
3. В секции Run выбираем Options.
4. Application Language -> далее из
       выпадающего списка выбрать Russian
       (или любой другой язык, который
       присутствует в Вашем проекте).
5. Clean -> Build & Go.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать всё из папки:
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

Временно переместите или удалите.

Comment: Не помогло.